# How to access the text of the <span> tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the dates from the soup that is scraping the google NEWS page

```
date_section = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw"})
print(date_section)
```

output:

```
[<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>30 May 2020</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>3 weeks ago</span></div>,
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>1 week ago</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>2 weeks ago</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>22 Nov 2020</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>19 Mar 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>18 Mar 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>11 Aug 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>1 Aug 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>4 Jun 2009</span></div>]
```

I want to get a `list` of all the dates from this structure.

This is how I'm currently accessing the date and can get a `list` of dates by looping. I was wondering if there is more elegant way of working with `BeautifulSoup` to access the dates in such a structure.

```
print("First date",date_section[0].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>30 May 2020</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>3 weeks ago</span></div>,
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>1 week ago</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>2 weeks ago</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>22 Nov 2020</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>19 Mar 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>18 Mar 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>11 Aug 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>1 Aug 2019</span></div>, 
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>4 Jun 2009</span></div>
'''

soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

date_section = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw"})
for d in date_section:
    print(d.text)
```

**Output:**

```
30 May 2020
3 weeks ago
1 week ago
2 weeks ago
22 Nov 2020
19 Mar 2019
18 Mar 2019
11 Aug 2019
1 Aug 2019
4 Jun 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a list of all the dates from this structure.

To get a `list` simply iterate your `ResultSet` e.g. with `list comprehension`:

```
[e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw"})]
```

or with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('div.OSrXXb.ZE0LJd.YsWzw span')]
```

both will lead to:

```
['30 May 2020', '3 weeks ago', '1 week ago', '2 weeks ago', '22 Nov 2020', '19 Mar 2019', '18 Mar 2019', '11 Aug 2019', '1 Aug 2019', '4 Jun 2009']
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>30 May 2020</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>3 weeks ago</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>1 week ago</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>2 weeks ago</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>22 Nov 2020</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>19 Mar 2019</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>18 Mar 2019</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>11 Aug 2019</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>1 Aug 2019</span></div>
<div class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw" style="bottom:0px"><span>4 Jun 2009</span></div>
'''

soup= BeautifulSoup(html)

[e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "OSrXXb ZE0LJd YsWzw"})]
```